# Can you curry functions passed as @Input in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, functional-programming, currying

I have set of modals with similar styling but completely different behavior I want to use in different scenarios in my app. So the easiest way for me to use them woutld be to pass logic as input in those various scenarios. With simple functions it works (let's assume my `custom-button` requires `() => Observable<any>` on click, so it can correctly lock until callback:

```js
export class SimpleComponent {
  @Input() fetchFun: () => Observable<any>;
}

export class ParentComponent {
  funToPass = () => this.httpService.getClients().pipe(...);
}
```

```html
// in parent component
  <simple-component
    [fetchFun]="funToPass">
  </simple-component>

// in simple component
  <form>
    <custom-button
      type="submit"
      (onClick)="fetchFun"
    ></custom-button>
  </form>
```

But as soon as I try to curry those functions with parameters from child components, I get `core.js:4610 ERROR TypeError: ctx.curriedFun is not a function`, for example:

```js
export class CurryComponent {
  @Input() curriedFun: (dto: Dto) => () => Observable<any>;
}

export class ParentComponent {
  funToPass = (dto:Dto) => () => this.httpService.getClients(dto).pipe(...);
}
```

```html
// in parent component
  <curry-component
    [curriedFun]="funToPass">
  </curry-component>

// in simple component
  <form>
    <custom-button
      type="submit"
      (onClick)="curriedFun(this.getDto())"
    ></custom-button>
  </form>
```

Can I pass functions like this to Angular components, or work somehow around this issue?

Comment: The correct way is to use an @Injectable service class. Put the method in there and inject the service in both components.

Comment: it's not `(onClick)="fetchFun()"`? -see the parenthesis- BTW, take a look the uiTeam's response (for me is better use `@Output`

Comment: @Eliseo nope, fetchFun() evaluates to ```Observable<any>```, and ```custom-button``` requires ```() => Observable<any>```

Answer (score 0):

use `@output` for this kind of scenarios. Trigger an `eventemitter` on click of your modal `component` button. Capture that event on your parent component and execute different methods based on your parent component logic.  Think differently, instead of passing function to child, pass data from child to parent and wrote the functional logic in parent.

Structure:

```
<parent-component>
 <modal-component></modal-component> 
</parent-component>
```

//modal component

```
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

 buttonClick(value: any) {
   this.valueChange.emit(value);
 }
```

//modal html

```
<button (click)="buttonClick(value)">Pass to parent</button>
```

//parent html

```
<parent-component (valueChange)='buttonClicked($event)'></parent-component>
```

//parent component

```
buttonClicked(event){
 //click logic
}
```